# VBA to check cells and display value found on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Currently working in Excel VBA for the first time and am looking to use a command button that when pushed will check values in 3 cells and then display a value found on another sheet in a cell below. So far i have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
= IF cells(b,1).Value2 = "A"
And cells(b,2).Value2 = "OO"
And cells(b,3).Value2 = "<48"
Then calls(b,10).Value2 = Worksheets("Rates"). cells(b,4)
End Sub
```

This was my first attempt although it is not working and im unsure how to move forward. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want your output to be? First thing I see is that you have a typo on `calls(b, 10)`. If you add `Option Explicit` to header (very top), it will act as a handy spell checker while forcing you to declare variables. Also, you do not start an `If` statement with the equals sign.

Comment: the output is a number "5.6" that is found on another sheet within the the "rates" sheet

Comment: Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
IF cells(b,1).Value2 = "A"
And cells(b,2).Value2 = "OO"
And cells(b,3).Value2 = "<48"
Then cells(b,10).Value2 = Worksheets("Rates"). cells(b,4)

End Sub

Comment: The "<48" will be in text as it is a list option for the

Comment: So the layout is cells B1 to B3 all have lists attached so i need it to check the cell text from each of the three and then if its a combo then it will display a rate thats found on the rate sheet of the workbook

Comment: Do you need VBA for this? Seems like you could just create a unique string `= B1 & B2 & B3` and then do a `VLOOKUP` to import to associated rate. This actually has less steps from a user perspective - all they have to do is select the 3 list options and the new sheet will update with associated value

Comment: I was going to use VBA just so the user could fill in the three fields then click a command button and on their answer display the rate in a designated cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things to note:

1. This can be done with a concatenated string and `VLOOKUP` (*if you are open to non-VBA solution*)
2. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your code, this will catch typos like `calls(b, 10)`
3. You do not start an `If` statement with =
4. The proper syntax for range reference with cells is `Cells(Row Index, Column Index)` - you have this backwards but since you are using static ranges, `Range` may be a little more intuitive
5. Try to qualify all objects with worksheets. Notice your `Cells` don't state which sheet each time. Be explicit and you are less likely to have errors in the future

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update

If ws.Range("B1") = "A" And ws.Range("B2") = "OO" and ws.Range("B3") = "<48" Then
    ws.Range("B10").Value = Worksheets("Rates").Range("B4").Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help it worked. I will also look into the concatenated string option as well.

Comment: @T.Mccallum - In my opinion the worksheet formula would likely be a better option if you're sharing the workbook with anyone.  That way it's a little more straightforward what's happening, if something needs to be changed. But this VBA solution obviously works too!